# trigger css animation when element in viewport

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

thanks so much for your eyes.

The Javascript is intended to delay the css animation until the user has the element within their viewport. When you run it, scroll down to see this element. If you move fast enough, you’ll see it scrolling, but it doesn’t wait.

i made a fiddle with my code in the state in which i believe it SHOULD work:

https://jsfiddle.net/3jvvvf4s/

I got the code from this site:

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#how

Yesterday, I got it working, but ONLY when I gave the  TWO class tags. So it looked something like

```
<img class=“lazy”  src=“png” class=“scroll_long”>
```

Combining classes OR turning 'lazy' info an ID didn't work.

I also tried this code, I got from somewhere else, with pretty much the same results:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
$('.lazy').each(function () {
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {
        $(this).addClass("scroll_long");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("scroll_long");
    }
});
```

});

Any thoughts would be sooo appreciated, I'm officially stumped!

Comment: you didn't include jquery in your fiddle.. just include it and it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

After I added the compound class to trigger the animation:

```
.for-anim.playit.scroll_long{ 
 animation: 5600ms cubic-bezier(0.694, 0, 0.335, 1) 1000ms normal forwards 1 running scrollScreen;
}
```

I had forgotten to delete the other style .scroll_long.

Thanks again!